# Authentfification at WooCommerce API giving Error

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

After porting my Website from One Server to an other on a new domain I can't get the authentication of a Plugin to the Woocomerce API. It shows following error message.

[image: Woocomerce Error Message]

Looks like there is something wrong - the Plugin is [QuizProduct](https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-recommendation-quiz-for-ecommerce/)
Up to know I went in the wp_conf file and defined the domain with following lines:

define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://www.mydomain.de');
define('WP_HOME', 'https://www.mydomain.de');

Thanks in Advance for any kind of help.